# How to monitor bluemix app usage using cloudfoundary/curl

Tags: curl, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I want to monitor app usage for that I am using `curl` command. It gives this error :

```
command: curl "https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/app_usage_events/guid-xxxxxxxxxxx" -X GET -H "Authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUxxxxxxxxxxCI6ImNmIiwiZ3JhbnRfdHlwZSI6InBhc3N3b3" -H "Cookie: "
```

> Error: { "code": 230002, "description": "Event could not be found:
>   guid-xxxxxxxxx", "error_code": "CF-EventNotFound" }

Answer (score 1):

*The [App Usage Events API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/217/app_usage_events/list_all_app_usage_events.html) is only available to platform admins, not individual users.*

Application users can use the [Event API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/217/events/list_all_events.html) to access similar information.

```
curl "https://api.[your-domain.com]/v2/events" -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoidWFhLWlkLTM0NyIsImVtYWlsIjoiZW1haWwtMjM4QHNvbWVkb21haW4uY29tIiwic2NvcGUiOlsiY2xvdWRfY29udHJvbGxlci5hZG1pbiJdLCJhdWQiOlsiY2xvdWRfY29udHJvbGxlciJdLCJleHAiOjE0NDE2NjI2MTR9.zafzzB3szzWSzto_IjBvDpmuWvpuHfil0QNqdyM60m0" \
    -H "Host: example.org" \
    -H "Cookie: "
```

Comment: using this how can i monitor app usage and calculate money based on app usage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor how much you are spending in Bluemix do the following.

1. Log into Bluemix
2. In the top right corner click on the person's head icon
3. Click account
4. The page that comes up will show you your monthly spend and break it down per application.

Comment: I'm using apidocs.cloudfoundary.org for fetching information to my application as well i want know the information of app usage to my application how to do that